# Using OpenGL VAO for different VBOs

Tags: opengl

I'm writing my own renderer for a game. I have a class Geometry, which encapsulates geometry data in form of VBOs (Vertex Buffer Objects). Geometry also has a reference to an object of type InputLayout, which stores information about geometry data. InputLayout instances are shared among Geometry instances. I'm using InputLayout to correctly configure the pipeline (e.g. glVertexAttribPointer()) before "draw call" (e.g. glDrawArrays()). Configuring routine is a bit inefficient, because I have to scan active vertex shader for its active attributes and then look for these attributes in active InputLayout instance. I would like to automate the whole process by using VAOs.

And here is the question. Should I create one VAO for each shader/InputLayout pair or for each shader/Geometry pair? By creating VAO for each shader/InputLayout pair, I will have to change buffer bindings in VAOs before every draw call. Is it worth to redesing my renderer and create VAO for each shader/Geometry pair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of using VAOs is so that you don't have to constantly change them. You bind a VAO and render. Since the associated buffer objects are *part* of VAO state, then the only way to do this is to have VAOs store the actual buffers, not just the "layout".

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. THX